# Adding two digital numbers

Tags: shell

I am trying to calculate amount of files, which I ftp to the different server. My code is below:

```
#!/bin/sh
cnt=0    
cnt=`expr $cnt+1`    
echo $cnt
```

and it gives me result:

```
0+1
```

I need it as `1`.

Could you please tell me what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `$(())` for calculations. For example, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cnt=0    
cnt=$((cnt + 1))    
echo $cnt
```

Taken from [2. Shell Command Language #Arithmetic Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04)

Comment: This code gives an error:    syntax error at line 6:    cnt=$ unexpected

Comment: @digioleg54 what if you use `cnt=$(($cnt + 1))`? That is, `$cnt` in the `$(())` expression.

Answer (score 2):

`expr`, unlike `$(( ))`, needs to receive separate shell arguments. So this will work:

```
cnt=`expr $cnt + 1`
```

and so will this

```
cnt=$((cnt+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cnt=0
((cnt++))

echo $cnt
1

((cnt++))
echo $cnt
2
```

Comment: Funny, I thought `sh` didn't allow `((cnt ++))`, unlike `bash`. I just tested and yes, it does! +1 for the variety of solutions.

Comment: @fedorqui Funny! When I saw your solution, I suddenly doubted my own solution and retried it too :-)

Answer (score 1):

The error is you do not have spaces before and after '+' sign.
Try surrounding math operator with spaces, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cnt=0    
cnt=`expr $cnt + 1`    
echo $cnt
```